# Integrate Firebase Analytics with Ionic 3

Tags: ionic3, firebase-analytics

I'm using Ionic 3 and I need to integrate Firebase Analytics in my app, I've followed the firebase instructions but can't build Android. I have the warning :

> "Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/release, src/release/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/release, src/nullnullRelease]"

and the error :

> - What went wrong:
>     The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.0.1.

My file google-service.json is in the folder "platforms/android/app" I don't really know if it's the right place...
Can someone help me understand what I have to do ? :(

Ps : Sorry for my english guys ^^'